# JNI Linking in Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna

I created a C++ function to add two numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
int add (int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

and created two classes in Java to access it using JNA:

```
package jniTest;
public class jnitest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:/cygwin/home/abc");
        System.loadLibrary("add");

        importClass lib = importClass.INSTANCE;
        System.out.println(lib.add(10, 20));
    }
}
```

Main test class:

```
package jniTest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface importClass extends Library
{
    importClass INSTANCE = (importClass) Native.loadLibrary("add", importClass.class);
    int add(int x, int y);
}
```

I am getting the following error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no add in java.library.path
"

Comment: Is your library file called "add"?

Comment: I am assuming library file is the C++ file that i have created to add two functions and the file name is add. Is that correct? sorry I am a newbie in this domain.

Comment: No, you need to compile it, same as any other C++ program or library.

Comment: i did compile it and created add.dll file.

Comment: You've missed a lot of what's needed to call native methods via JNI.  Your best approach would be to start by reading some of the tutorials listed here:  https://www.google.com/search?q=java+jni+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of your problems are caused and a lot of confusion in the comments by thinking you are using JNI directly rather than JNA.

Since you are using JNA, you should set jna.library.path rather than java.library.path and you should not call System.loadLibrary() as you would if you were using JNI directly.

Change your main class to:

```
package jniTest;
public class jnitest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // changed java to jna in next line.
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:/cygwin/home/abc");
        // remove this line System.loadLibrary("add");

        importClass lib = importClass.INSTANCE;
        System.out.println(lib.add(10, 20));
    }
}
```